# How to use list comprehension for nested for loops in PySpark

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, pyspark, list-comprehension

I intend to use difflib.SequenceMatcher() on the below PySpark data frames.

```
tech.show()

+-----------------------------+----------------------+
|        concat_tech          |Vendor_product        |
+-----------------------------+----------------------+
|AWS Cloud Administration     |AWS Cloud Map         |
|Grad Portal                  |CA Identity Portal    |
|Html/php                     |HTML                  |
|UX Xpect                     |HP-UX                 |
|Debian-based                 |Debian                |
|Microsoft Office excel       |Microsoft Office      |
|Oracle EBusiness Suite 12.2.4|Oracle Primavera Suite|
|Solaris 10.XX                |Solaris               |
|CA7 Job Scheduler            |CA Scheduler          |
|Windows NT/XP/Vista          |Windows XP            |
+-----------------------------+----------------------+

techno.show()
+------------------------------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
|vendor                        |product                        |category                        |sub_category                                       |
+------------------------------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
|Notion Labs, Inc.             |Notion                         |Project Management              |Project Management                                 |
|Apptricity Corporation        |Apptricity                     |Enterprise Applications         |Enterprise Resource Planning (ERP)                 |
|Resolution Software, Ltd.     |Xcase                          |IT Governance                   |Application Development & Management               |
|The Apache Software Foundation|Apache Mynewt                  |IT Governance                   |Application Development & Management               |
|NetApp, Inc.                  |NetApp iSCSI SAN Storage System|Data Center Solutions           |Data Management & Storage (Hardware)               |
|HP, Inc.                      |HP Z820                        |Hardware (Basic)                |Consumer Electronics, Personal Computers & Software|
|Dell Technologies, Inc.       |Dell EMC FormWare              |Customer Relationship Management|Help Desk Management                               |
|ServiceMax, Inc.              |ServiceMax                     |Customer Relationship Management|Service & Field Support Management                 |
|MaxMind, Inc.                 |MaxMind GeoIP                  |Software (Basic)                |Server Technologies (Software)                     |
|Campus Management Corporation |Campus Management              |Vertical Markets                |Academic & Education Management Software           |
+------------------------------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
import pandas as pd
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
def similar(a,b):
    if pd.isnull(a) or pd.isnull(b):
        return 0
    else:
        return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
```

The function SequenceMatcher(a, b) takes *concat_tech* from data frame *tech* as 'a' and *product* from data frame *techno* as 'b' and returns a ratio between a and b. The goal is to find the best match for the *concat_tech* among all the *product* and return a data frame with the best match, i.e. one *product* will be returned from the *product* column for which the best(maximum) ratio is generated for a value of *concat_tech* using SequenceMatcher().

It is supposed to be a one-to-many operation that could be done using list comprehension in pandas but how to achieve the same in PySpark? I have millions of rows in both the data frames, here I have given a sample of 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare each element from dataframe `tech` with each element from dataframe `techno`. The result of such an operation is a [crossJoin](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.crossJoin). Unless either one side of this join is rather small or there is a way to reduce the amount of possible combinations (thus avoiding the cross join), this will be a very costly operation.

The actual code is straight forward: do the join, calculate the ratios of each pair with the help of an [udf](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python.html) and then find the max for each element from `tech`:

```python
import pandas as pd
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

@F.udf("double")
def similar(a,b):
    if pd.isnull(a) or pd.isnull(b):
        return 0
    else:
        return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

df = tech.select("concat_tech").crossJoin(techno.select("product")) \
    .withColumn("ratio", similar("concat_tech", "product")) \
    .groupBy("concat_tech").agg(F.expr("max_by(product, ratio)"), F.max("ratio"))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output for the example data:

```
+--------------------------+----------------------+-------------------+         
|concat_tech               |max_by(product, ratio)|max(ratio)         |
+--------------------------+----------------------+-------------------+
|UXXpect                   |Apptricity            |0.35294117647058826|
|GradPortal                |Notion                |0.25               |
|OracleEBusinessSuite12.2.4|ApacheMynewt          |0.3157894736842105 |
|MicrosoftOfficeexcel      |ServiceMax            |0.3333333333333333 |
|AWSCloudAdministration    |Notion                |0.35714285714285715|
|CA7JobScheduler           |ApacheMynewt          |0.37037037037037035|
|Html/php                  |HPZ820                |0.14285714285714285|
|WindowsNT/XP/Vista        |MaxMindGeoIP          |0.3333333333333333 |
|Debian-based              |Xcase                 |0.35294117647058826|
|Solaris10.XX              |Xcase                 |0.23529411764705882|
+--------------------------+----------------------+-------------------+
```

The usage of a [Vectorized UDF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/user_guide/arrow_pandas.html#pandas-udfs-a-k-a-vectorized-udfs) might improve the performance a bit, but the cross join would still be problem for large dataframes.

Comment: Thanks, Werner, this worked. Nevertheless, as you pointed out- quite a costly operation